# Error adding spring-security 3.2.5 to project with spring-core 4.1.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have an issue.
I am working in a project with spring 4.1.2.RELEASE, recently I tried to add spring-security 3-2-5 but then my project fails to deploy.

The exception after adding springsecurity dependencies was:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy

I was searching and reading and I found I should change spring-core to previous version so I fall back to spring-core 4.0.1 which includes MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy class.

But when I do that anboter exceptions throws at deploying project

NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/core/SpringNamingPolicy

I read again but not found any good explanation or solution.

And before I go ahead changing my versions again more and more I want to know if someone has a solution for this, or in which page can I see compatibility between versions and not go trying one by one.

Here is my pom (the original before I started changing versions)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.controlescolar</groupId>
  <artifactId>ControlEscolar</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>ControlEscolar Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.34</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>el-impl</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt-hibernate4</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/target</directory>
    <finalName>ControlEscolar</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/home/pedro/eclipse_workspace/ControlEscolar/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

And my aplicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <import resource="security.xml"/>

    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity /-->
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/properties/jdbc.properties"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controlescolar.model" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controlescolar.daoimpl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controlescolar.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controlescolar.controller" />

    <bean id="jasyptStringDigester" class="org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester" >
        <property name="algorithm" value="SHA-512" />
        <property name="iterations" value="1001" />
    </bean>

    <!--bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.jasypt.spring.security3.PasswordEncoder">
        <property name="stringDigester">
            <ref bean="jasyptStringDigester" />
        </property>
    </bean-->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
      <property name="username"  value="${jdbc.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>                             
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="controlescPU"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
        <property name="database" value="${jpa.database}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" />
        <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.showSql}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages/messages" />
    </bean>    

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Try deleting the .m2/repository folder and importing the dependencies again.

Comment: I did twice, one with spring 4.1.2 and one with 4.0.1 but no way, the same exceptions throws again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, today I just tried adding the dependency aop and change to 4.1.2.RELEASE and everything it works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

You must resolve dependencies conflict in Spring Security libraries.
This [**article**](http://techidiocy.com/maven-dependency-version-conflict-problem-and-resolution/) should help you.